# ElasticSearch keyword match vector

Tags: python, elasticsearch, keyword, elk

first of all, sorry if what I'm asking is stupid, but I'm very new to Elastic Search. Here's what I need to do: I have an array of keywords that I need to search for in every document of an index. Here's the mapping:

```json
{
  "resumes": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Knowing this, I need to search for all the words in the keyword array in every document, and for every document in the resume index, it would return a vector with 0 for the word if not found in the document, and 1 if it was found.

Eg.

```
keywords = ["javascript", "html", "python"]
doc1 = "Hello there, I've only programmed in python."
doc2 = "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript."
doc3 = "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript. Im now learning html"
```

Search results would be something like:

```json
{
  "doc1": [0, 0, 1], // because it contains the word python
  "doc2": [1, 0, 1], // because it contains both python and javascript
  "doc3": [1, 1, 1]  // because it contains all words in the keyword vector
}
```

Is it even possible to do this with elastic search alone?
I'm coding all this in Python, but I think if I filled these with Python itself, it would be way more inefficient than if elastic search could do it.

Haven't tried much yet, since I don't even know too well the capabilities of Elastic Search. I've searched a lot for it, but I'm not even aware where to start from...

Comment: Elastic return the documents and score relevant. Why you need this vector like response?

Comment: It is a requirement for what I'm building that i need to get the object with those vectors. The problem is I dont know if Elastic Search can do it by itself (and according to your answer, if I understood correctly, it cannot). What would be the approach you'd suggest to getting that object? Cuz the only way i can think of is iterating over every word in keywords array, search for it on elasticsearch, and create the vectors with python according to the documents returned... Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using scripts in elasticsearch is not healthy because they are not performative. I managed to do what you want but I warn you about performance issues.

In field "vector_field" your have your matrix.

```
POST idx_teste/_doc 
{
  "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python."
}

POST idx_teste/_doc 
{
  "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript."
}

POST idx_teste/_doc 
{
  "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript. Im now learning html"
}

GET idx_teste/_search
{
  "_source": "*", 
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "description": [
        "javascript","html","python"
      ]
    }
  }, 
   "script_fields": {
     "custom_field": {
       "script": {
         "source":  """
              def vector = new ArrayList();
              for(int i=0; i< params.keywords.size(); i++){
                String text = doc['description.keyword'].value;
                if(text.contains(params.keywords[i])) {
                  vector.add(1);
                } else {
                  vector.add(0);
                }
              }
              return vector;
          """,
          "params": {
            "keywords" :[
                "javascript","html","python"
              ]
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Response:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "idx_teste",
        "_id": "oIyiQ4QBgXg8h_rc0Ny3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python."
        },
        "fields": {
          "vector_field": [
            0,
            0,
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_teste",
        "_id": "oYypQ4QBgXg8h_rcH9wU",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript."
        },
        "fields": {
          "vector_field": [
            1,
            0,
            1
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_teste",
        "_id": "ooypQ4QBgXg8h_rcJ9y2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "description": "Hello there, I've only programmed in python and javascript. Im now learning html"
        },
        "fields": {
          "vector_field": [
            1,
            1,
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you very much for your help! I tried it with the exact same data you provided, and it worked perfectly! I noticed it works well in text that is correctly spaced, but if the field is a text without any spaces (eg. text with all spaces removed), it doesn't work. Im guessing the `string.contains()` method doesnt work like "substring matching"? Any idea why that is the case? I'm setting the answer as the solution, since it does work, but not correctly for this specific case. Thank you very much once again!

Comment: The text would be like this: "Hellothere,I'veonlyprogrammedinpythonandjavascript"? Really term query will not work, this case match all works.

Comment: Indeed with `match_all` its working perfectly! Thank you very much once again!